# Multiple classes: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, class

I have officially come to the end of my rope. I cannot find what I did wrong. I have done this program almost exactly like another program I wrote a few days ago but I am having problems compiling. I do not know why I am getting errors on the output lines. Please help:

THIS IS THE RUNNING FILE:

```
package inventory1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    DataCollection theProduct = new DataCollection();

    String Name = "";
    double pNumber = 0.0;
    double Units = 0.0;
    double Price = 0.0;

    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Enter Product Name: ");
      Name = input.next();
      theProduct.setName(Name);
      if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        return;}    
      System.out.print("Enter Product Number: ");
      pNumber = input.nextDouble();
      theProduct.setpNumber(pNumber);

      System.out.print("Enter How Many Units in Stock: ");
      Units = input.nextDouble();
      theProduct.setUnits(Units);

      System.out.print("Enter Price Per Unit: ");
      Price = input.nextDouble();
      theProduct.setPrice(Price);

      System.out.print("\n Product Name:     " + theProduct.getName());
      System.out.print("\n Product Number:     " + theProduct.getpNumber());
      System.out.print("\n Amount of Units in Stock:     " + theProduct.getUnits());
      System.out.print("\n Price per Unit:    " + theProduct.getPrice()  + "\n\n");
      System.out.printf("\n Total cost for %s in stock: $%.2f\n\n\n", theProduct.getName(), theProduct.calculatePrice());

    }
  }
}
```

THIS IS THE DATA COLLECTIONS FILE:

```
package inventory1;

public class DataCollection {
  String productName;
  double productNumber, unitsInStock, unitPrice, totalPrice;

  public DataCollection() {
    productName = "";
    productNumber = 0.0;
    unitsInStock = 0.0;
    unitPrice = 0.0;
  }

  // setter methods
  public void setName(String name) {
    productName = name;
  }

  public void setpNumber(double pNumber) {
    productNumber = pNumber;
  }

  public void setUnits(double units) {
    unitsInStock = units;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price) {
    unitPrice = price;
  }

  // getter methods
  public void getName(String name) {
    productName = name;
  }

  public void getpNumber(double pNumber) {
    productNumber = pNumber;
  }

  public void getUnits(double units) {
    unitsInStock = units;
  }

  public void getPrice(double price) {
    unitPrice = price;
  }

  public double calculatePrice() {
    return (unitsInStock * unitPrice);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please format your code properly 2) What errors are you getting?

Comment: Same as Zulan...  Difficult to help without well formatted code and more info.

Comment: I formatted his code, long auto indent!

Comment: Sorry I had a problem posting and couldnt get in to change/correct it.

Comment: The compiler loves you. Read the errors. Know the errors. Love the errors. All the information needed for a happy family is in the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't compile is because your main code:

```
  System.out.print("\n Product Name:     " + theProduct.getName());
  System.out.print("\n Product Number:     " + theProduct.getpNumber());
  System.out.print("\n Amount of Units in Stock:     " + theProduct.getUnits());
  System.out.print("\n Price per Unit:    " + theProduct.getPrice()  + "\n\n");
  System.out.printf("\n Total cost for %s in stock: $%.2f\n\n\n", theProduct.getName(), theProduct.calculatePrice());
```

Requires `getName()` But your getName() implementation did not exist. You didn't have the proper signature. Change it to a proper getter and it should work. Same goes for the other getters.

Instead of:

```
  // getter methods
  public void getName(String name) {
    productName = name;
  }

  public void getpNumber(double pNumber) {
    productNumber = pNumber;
  }

  public void getUnits(double units) {
    unitsInStock = units;
  }

  public void getPrice(double price) {
    unitPrice = price;
  }
```

Use:

```
  // getter methods
  public String getName() {
    return productName;
  }

  public double getpNumber() {
    return productNumber;
  }

  public double getUnits() {
    return unitsInStock;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
  }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I am still learning the different methods and sometimes I get a little lost. Thank you for your help @Mohamed Mansour

Comment: No worries, I highly recommend http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ for starters :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the way you are reading the values. While it is safe to read `Strings` using `Scanner.next()` but for other data structures you might need to clear a new line character from your input stream before you actually read the value.

But this is only in theory because you have given virtually nothing about your problem.